# How can I pause in the middle of the execution of a MSBuild script?

Tags: msbuild

I tried to use:

```
<Exec Command="pause" />
```

But that doesn't work. Please help to to pause!

Nam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) has a **Prompt** task that sounds like it will work for you. I've never used it myself, so can't say from experience.

Answer (score 7):

I've tried Prompt task with an sample script as below. It works. Thank you!
Nam.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="MAIN" >
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

  <Target Name="MAIN">
    <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Prompt Text="Press any key..." >
      <Output TaskParameter="UserInput" PropertyName="out" />
    </MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Prompt>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Updated to "Press enter..." :)